# Travellerspoint map functionality

Tags: google-maps

I want to develop something like [Travellerspoint](http://www.travellerspoint.com/member_map.cfm). Can someone guide me how can i achieve it? I tried Google maps but that doesn't give me all map functionality as they have created.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using OpenLayers. There is a showcase which includes some source code for the functions.

Showcase

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/

Wiki

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLayers

Comment: You may need to add more detail to your question. What do you want the web/app to do first? Once you have a less general question people can give a less general answer.  What functionality are you missing?